# Validation Form, warning of empty fields dissapears, last about 3 miliseconds

Tags: javascript, html

Validation form, if the user doesn´t enter text in the fields, the name of the field is added to a array called flag, then the function errormsg insert text in the input fields leting them know that they forgot to fill the field. **it works but only for about three miliseconds**, any idea why?

```js
var flag = [];

function validar(form) {
  if (form.name.value == "") {
    flag.push("name");
  }
  if (form.email.value == "") {
    flag.push("email");
  }
  if (form.message.value == "") {
    flag.push("message");
  }
  errorMsg(flag);
  flag.length = 0;
}

function errorMsg(flag) {
  for (var i = 0; i < flag.length; i++) {
    var errorname = document.getElementById(flag[i]);
    errorname.value += "You Must Enter " + flag[i];
  }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return validar(this)">
  <label for="name">Nombre</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
  <label for="email">Email</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br>
  <label for="message">Mensaje</label><br>
  <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea><br>
  <button type="submit" name="button">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check to see if there are any elements in `flag` - if there are, then call `preventDefault()` to prevent the form from submitting. To do this, you'll also need a reference to the submit event (*not* the form itself). Inline handlers are as bad as `eval`, so attach the listener in Javascript instead. You can also create a new `flag` array every time `validar` is called instead of manually resetting its length to `0` each time:

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', validar);
function validar(event) {
  var flag = [];
  if (form.name.value == "") {
    flag.push("name");
  }
  if (form.email.value == "") {
    flag.push("email");
  }
  if (form.message.value == "") {
    flag.push("message");
  }
  if (flag.length > 0) {
    errorMsg(flag);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}

function errorMsg(flag) {
  for (var i = 0; i < flag.length; i++) {
    var errorname = document.getElementById(flag[i]);
    errorname.value += "You Must Enter " + flag[i];
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="name">Nombre</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
  <label for="email">Email</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br>
  <label for="message">Mensaje</label><br>
  <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea><br>
  <button type="submit" name="button">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Note that this would be easier by giving the `input`s in question a `required` attribute, no Javascript required:

```html
<form>
  <label for="name">Nombre</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required><br>
  <label for="email">Email</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required><br>
  <label for="message">Mensaje</label><br>
  <textarea name="message" id="message" required></textarea><br>
  <button type="submit" name="button">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks man, it work in the snippet, but in my machine trows me an error  "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Comment: Make sure you run the Javascript *after* the page is parsed. Make sure it's in a separate file and give its HTML tag the `defer` attribute.

Comment: Also, see edit - better to give the elements a `required` attribute.